# Complete requirements for HTML E-mail Contact Forms

Tags: php, html, security, email, contact-form

Everywhere I've looked, from youtube, to w3schools, to the php manual (just to mention a few), none of them provided in-depth details about the requirements of successfully sending a secure email from a simple contact form...

Construction of the form and client/server validation aside, **what exactly do I need to know to securely send the results via email using the php mail() function?** (since it's not a heavy task for which Perl works better according to the PHP manual).

What is SMTP?, what is authentication and in what case do I need it?, what are headers?, what is x-mailer?, how exactly do I implement it all together, and what have I missed?

Comment: I hope someone answers this is detail :D

Comment: What do you mean by secure? Encrypted?

Comment: At risk of sounding horribly cynical - if SMTP is an unknown, secure email may well be a huge step. Flagged as not a real question - this is a whole heap of questions:-)

Comment: So, in other words you want us to do your research? Why not try those questions on a search engine, such as google. Seems like they are all answered pretty well.

Comment: @webbiedave - If possible, then yes.

@Shef - I'm not asking anyone for any research...I'm asking for some clarity and for those taht are kind enough, to share a bit of wisdom. If google actually did help, I wouldn't be asking now would I?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as secure e-mail.  It generally floats across the internet in plain text.

Unless you are encrypting before sending, and the client has something to decrypt it with on their end, there is nothing you can do.

This is usually handled by storing the message on a server accessible via HTTPS, and e-mailing the person a link to it.  Then, they login and view the message.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was some really good information!

Answer (score 1):

In all honesty, you might be better off going with an email service provider that sends out transactional messages. They will have libraries for you to use with your PHP files and you won't have to worry about all of the requirements for emails, just shoot them through their systems.

Many of the larger ones have free accounts, so unless you are sending more than 30-50 emails a day, they should work well for you.

Here are the list of the bigger ones:

- [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com) (Mine!)
- [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com)
- [PostmarkApp](http://postmarkapp.com)

Take a look at all of these and figure out what works best for you. Best of luck!

(**Full Disclosure:** I am the Product Manager of PostageApp.)

Comment: Thank you JonLim! I've tried those before and even though they worked, I wasn't quite satisfied with them...not that there's anything wrong with them, it's just that, I don't feel comfortable using something that is already pre-made...Honestly, if I knew how to make one properly, It wouldn't bother me to use one of those services...it's just for knowledge...

Comment: I only suggest them because it isn't the emails that are difficult, I would say it's the maintenance of the SMTP server, ensuring emails get delivered, and harvesting all the good information you might need. But power to you, good sir/madam!

Comment: Yes you've got a point there! I'll keep that in mind for the future and again thanks!